# Can I align table headers with table columns using ng-repeat in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I modified code from the meanjs generators lists to create a table instead of a list. However, the first header covers both of the columns of data and the second header extends to the right by itself and doesn't cover anything. Is there anyway to align these columns with the headers with or without using ng-table (preferable without)? I am new to angular and to stack overflow, so I apologize in advance if this is somehow a repeated question or unclear.

```
    <div class="list-group">
    <table class="list-group-table">
      <tr><th class="list-todos-left-header">Project and Task</th><th class="list-todos-right-header">Author Date</th></tr>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="list-group-item">
          <td class="list-todos-left-col">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="todo.title"></h4>
            <a class="list-group-item-text" data-ui-sref="todos.view({todoId: todo._id})" data-ng-bind="todo.content"></a>
          </td>
          <td class="list-todos-right-col">
            <table>
                <tr><td><span data-ng-bind="todo.created | date:'mediumDate'"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span data-ng-bind="todo.user.displayName"></span></td></tr>

            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-users {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
    .list-group-table {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border: 3px inset #000000; 
}
    .list-group-item{
  background-color: #CCCCCC;

}
    .list-group-item-heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: yellow;
}
    .list-todos-left-header {
  max-width: 70%;
  min-width: 60%;
  border: 2px inset #111111;
}
    .list-todos-left-col {
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px inset #111111;
}
    .list-todos-right-col {
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px inset #111111;
}
    .list-todos-right-header {
  max-width: 20%;
  min-width: 20%;
  border: 2px outset #000000;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your css? Specifically the header classes css

Comment: Neither `<table>` can contain `<small>` element nor `<small>` can contain `<tr>`s. Even Angular can help you with that.

Comment: @nayish I add the CSS you requested

Comment: @c-smile I removed the small element and the class contained in the tag.

Comment: Shouldn't the `width`, `min-width`, `height` and `min-height` of the `th` and their respective `td` be the same?